# Management issues through Blynk

Tags: esp8266, blynk

I wrote a sketch for controlling the stepper motor under the controls of the Blynk application, the sketch was compiled but there was a problem in that no control was taking place. Receipts and controls occur on virtual pins V1, V2, V3. (The problem is that nothing is controlled), please help solve the problem.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
//#include <Stepper.h>
//#define BLYNK_WRITE
//#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
//#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
// for your motor
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 1, 2, 3, 4);

// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "[private]";

// Your WiFi credentials.
// Set password to "" for open networks.
char ssid[] = "S30mini";
char pass[] = "12345678";

int pinData;
int pinData1;
int pinData2;
BLYNK_WRITE(V3) //Button Widget is writing to pin V1
{
  int pinData = param.asInt(); 
 }
BLYNK_WRITE(V2) //Button Widget is writing to pin V1
{
  int pinData1 = param.asInt(); 
 }
BLYNK_WRITE(V1) //Button Widget is writing to pin V1
{
  int pinData2 = param.asInt(); 
 }

void setup()
{
  // Debug console
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
}

void loop()
{  
    Blynk.run();


  // map it to a range from 0 to 100:
  int motorSpeed = map(pinData, 0, 1023, 0, 100);
  // set the motor speed:
  if (motorSpeed > 0) {
    myStepper.setSpeed(motorSpeed);
    // step 1/100 of a revolution:
    myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution / 100);
  }

   if (pinData1 == 1){
      myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
   }

   if (pinData2 == 1){
     myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By prefixing your `pinData` variables with `int`, you are declaring local variables in your `BLYNK_WRITE()` functions, whose scope is only in that function. The local version is written to, instead of the global.

To fix this, do not declare a new variable in `BLYNK_WRITE()`:

```
BLYNK_WRITE(V3) //Button Widget is writing to pin V1
{
  pinData = param.asInt(); 
}
BLYNK_WRITE(V2) //Button Widget is writing to pin V1
{
  pinData1 = param.asInt(); 
}
BLYNK_WRITE(V1) //Button Widget is writing to pin V1
{
  pinData2 = param.asInt(); 
}
```